# NoSQL Word Proximity

Tags: search, lucene, full-text-search, nosql

Are there any NoSQL databases that support word proximity searching similar to [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html)?

I have a client that would like the flexibility of NoSQL with the search power of a Lucene or some other search tool. The average amount of data to be searched is 200GB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can manage a .NET/Win solution also check out RavenDB - has lucene baked into it.  If not, Schild's answer is a good one. You can also use lucene separately with MongoDB but your app would have to maintain the index itself...

Comment: I have also read that RavenDB will run on mono/linux with the Munin managed storage plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at tjake's [Solandra](https://github.com/tjake/Lucandra) (former Lucandra). "Solandra is a real-time distributed search engine built on Apache Solr and Apache Cassandra."

Solandra "supports most out-of-the-box Solr functionality (search, faceting, highlights)"

Answer (score 1):

[Lucene is a NoSQL database](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2010/04/29/for-the-guardian-solr-is-the-new-database/).

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late to be useful but check out [MarkLogic](http://developer.marklogic.com/).  It's a document database with integrated full-text search (not bolt-on Lucene).  You can see a quick demo via http://developer.marklogic.com/try/corona/index